# Is there a way to increase the token expiration time of Speakeasy

Tags: javascript, node.js, speakeasy

Currently i am using speakeasy to generate a OTP for two factor authentication.

```
speakeasy.totp({
      secret,
      encoding: 'base32'
});
```

I am generating the token using this. Its expiration time is 30s.

Can anyone know how to increase it?

I tried this. But it always return true when verifying the token.

```
speakeasy.totp({
      secret,
      encoding: 'base32',
      time: 60,
});

speakeasy.totp.verify({
      secret: secretKey,
      encoding: 'base32',
      token: code,
      time : 60
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try
{
step: 60,//in minute(30sec defaultx2)
window:5,//expiry set to 5 minute
}

Answer (score 0):

The `time` option actually will not change the expiration time of the token .

What you need is the `step` option to modify the expire time like this :

```js
speakeasy.totp({
      secret,
      encoding: 'base32',
      step : 300 // Expire token in 5 minutes
});

speakeasy.totp.verify({
      secret: secretKey,
      encoding: 'base32',
      token: code,
      step : 300 // Expire token in 5 minutes
});
```